# Altair: Nested Grouped Bar Chart with Conditional Coloring Based on External Data - Seeking Assistance with Complex Implementation

Tags: visualization

I'm currently tackling a challenging data visualization task using Altair in Python and aiming to create a nested grouped bar chart with conditional coloring based on external data. Here's the structure of my data:

- Primary categorical variable: A
- Secondary categorical variable: B
- Subcategories within A
- External dataset C, which contains conditions for conditional coloring

I've attempted to achieve this using Altair's layering approach and encoding, but integrating the nested grouping and conditional coloring has proven more intricate than expected. Here's a simplified version of my attempt:

```
chart = alt.Chart(df).mark_bar().encode(
x='A:N',
y='count():Q',
color=alt.condition(
condition='datum.condition \> threshold',  # Placeholder condition, looking to integrate conditions from df_cond
yes=alt.value('green'),
no=alt.value('red')
)
)

chart += alt.Chart(df).mark_bar().encode(
x='B:N',
y='count():Q',
color='A:N'
)
chart.show()
```

I'm struggling to incorporate the nested grouping within A and B while dynamically applying the conditional coloring based on the external conditions in C. Any insights, corrections, or alternative approaches to achieve this complex visualization would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Can you merge the dataframes before passing them to altair (otherwise you need to use a lookup transform in altair https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/transform/lookup.html)?

Does grouping the bar chart with the offset encoding as in this example help? https://altair-viz.github.io/gallery/grouped_bar_chart2.html If not, could you paste a short snippet of your data as text in the question so that others can reproduce the issue?